# Google tasks menu bar app for mac os x

Tags: macos, gmail

Is it there any free widget/program for mac os x that connects with google tasks and clicking on the menu bar allows to add more tasks and view info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/) app pointed to [mail.google.com/tasks/ig?pli=1](https://mail.google.com/tasks/ig?pli=1). (The [iOS version](https://mail.google.com/tasks/iphone) isn't really meant to be used with a keyboard and mouse.)

[image: google tasks fluid]

*Pin to Status Bar* (menu bar) is a paid feature though.

Or *Safari - File - Open in Dashboard...* for the Dashboard equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I use a cool small Adobe AIR program (called "[google tasks](http://www.jashsayani.com/my-softwares/)") that runs on mac osx. Though is not a menu bar app, it is pretty cool, lets yoou use gmail, calendar and all other utils from google too. I tried using fluid app too, but calendar did not work in it, and it does in this program.